# Send post request from mobile application built with Trigger.io

Tags: javascript, zepto, trigger.io, http-post

Basically the above, I need my mobile application (which is built with Trigger) to send a Post request to a remote server. Specifically, the application generates GPS coordinates and a timestamp and sends the data to a server (which is built with Ruby on Rails), which takes the data and stores it. I'm using the Zepto library to send it. How do I go about achieving this?

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/zepto.js"></script></head>

$.post(
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    data: {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude;
    longitude: position.coords.longitude;
    timestamp: new Date().getTime();},
    success: alert("Report Successful");
);
```

This is the code that actually sends the request. I don't believe that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like you're using geolocation too? See http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [forge.request.ajax](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/request.html#request.ajax).

Additionally, there are a couple of problems with your JavaScript code. This snippet should work to do the post (assuming that 'position' is defined earlier in your code):

```
forge.request.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    url: "http://yourserver",
    data: {},
    success: function() { alert("Report Successful"); }
});
```

Comment: Note on the success callback - wrapping it in a function () { } means the alert is only processed *after* the request is complete, rather than before.